# Check if a function exists based on a string in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I know, that in plain javascript, one can do the following, to check if a function is defined:

```
var functionNameToTest = 'function_name';

if (typeof window[functionNameToTest] === 'function') {
   console.log("It exists!");
}
```

But how could I do the same in `nodejs` for example, or in a windowless javascript? I know that I can `eval` it, but is that really the only solution for this?

Comment: in nodejs, the global object is named `global`. This way still only works in odd situations, where you pollute the global namespace with functions.

Comment: u can also use 'this' just like in UMD definition

Comment: what if I want to check for the function of a class? do I use `InstantiatedClass[functionNameToTest]`, or `ClassDefinition[functionNameToTest]` ?

Comment: when you create one, you use 'new', and store the reference somewhere. It can be static on the class itself or somewhere else. That's up to you. Create a ledger like ``this.ledger = {}` and store instantiated classes inside. This is looking like an A, B , C problem to me. What exactly is the end goal?